# How to get DayOfWeek in a local CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, cultureinfo

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
string day = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
day = day.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
MessageBox.Show(day); // result is "F"
```

How could I get the result in a local language (CultureInfo), for example - France and where can I find a list of languages references for this purpose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the MSDN: [MSDN on DateTime with CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
// Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
// and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));
```

Comment: ThankYou, Mare, the code works, but on the link there is no a list of cultureinfo shotcuts for every language.

Comment: I wouldn't change the current culture just to format something in a particular culture. I'd specify it explicitly in the ToString call.

Comment: @Alegro: You can find a list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The format string **d** gives you the Short Date (11/19/2015). Use **ddd**  (Thu) or **dddd** (Thursday) instead.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1JR8e

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you've already got the `CultureInfo`, you can use:

```
string dayName = dateTime.ToString("dddd", culture);
```

You'd then need to take the first character of it yourself - there's no custom date/time format for just that. You could use `ddd` for the *abbreviated* day name, but that's typically three characters, not one.

As for a list of cultures - you can use [`CultureInfo.GetCultures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx). It will vary by platform, and could vary over time and even by version of .NET, too.

As an aside, this code isn't ideal:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

If you happen to call it *just* before midnight at the end of a year, you could get the "old" year but then January as the month. You should evaluate `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.Today`) once, and then use the same value twice:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Joh, it is usefull for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try `dt.ToString("dddd")` and then manipulate that string if necessary. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime    dateValue    =    new    DateTime(2008,    6,    11);      
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ddd",    
                  new    CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is as simple as this:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
var datestring =datetime.ToString("dd MMMMM yyyy kl. hh:mm",culture)
```